# "Если не надо () отдай". Тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Здесь возможна постановка и тире, и запятой? Или что-то одно?

> Ну дак, если не надо () отдай.

Comment: >Ну дак...

Северный говор разрастается. ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно поставить тире

Answer (score 0):

Союз "если" находится в в придаточной части СПП. Должна быть запятая. А вот если бы союза не было, тогда, конечно, надо выбрать тире. Условие бы предполагалось.